# Write complete data to image file

Tags: java, android, stream

```
       int count = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192]; // more if you like but no need for
        int j = length_img % 8192;
        int value = length_img - j;
        int incre = 0;// it to be the entire file size

        for (int i = 0; i < (value / 8192) + 1; i++) {

            if (length_img == incre + j) {
                buffer = new byte[j];
                int pair = dataInputStream.read(buffer);
                System.out.print("i am here for last chunk" + buffer.length
                        + "value of j is" + j + "incre value is" + incre
                        + "the value of i is" + i
                        + "and the value of count is" + pair);

                image0OutFile.write(buffer, 0, pair);
                break;
            }

            else {
                count = dataInputStream.read(buffer);
                image0OutFile.write(buffer, 0, count);
                incre += 8192;
            }
        }
```

this is the part where some problem lies.i am getting this output length_img : 3147850
[B@72d86c58
i am here for last chunk2122value of j is2122incre value is3145728the value of i is384and the value of count is496bublo ... if you notice the value of pair should be 2122 but instead its 496 which is why file is corrupting.

Answer (score 2):

You should close the `FileOutputStream` :

`image0OutFile.close`

This would flush the final part to the file. Or you can even call:

`image0OutFile.flush()`

But the previous one is recommended. And you should ALWAYS close the streams you open.

Comment: i am closing the stream didnt  include that in code but i am doing it.the problem is to be more precise value of PAIR changes that is  image0OutFile.write(buffer, 0, pair); here the value of pair is changed as compared to buffer.length.i just checked it after printing

Answer (score 0):

**Always close streams**

Put your code in `Try catch` block first.Close the stream in `Finally` block.

```
finally{
        image0OutFile.close();
      }
```

And do not go for flush.When close called automatically flush happens.